# Is there a way to make a custom object parcelable when it is constructed using another object?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, parcelable

I'm writing an application to interface with an automotive classifieds API. I want to have two windows: one where the user types in the kind of car they want, and one where the results are displayed.

My API returns a large JSON file, on the verge of roughly 40 parameters per vehicle, of which only about 20 have any interest to me. I have a custom class to store some of the data returned by the API. In the constructor for this class (called CarListing), I pass a JSONObject and do my JSON parsing inside the constructor.

This class is then invoked inside of a threaded HttpGet activity, which itself is called by the MainActivity. So, for a given search, I expect to get more than one result from the API. I am able to successfully return the custom objects to the MainActivity, but I am having issues with sending this data from the MainActivity to a SecondActivity. Eventually, I'd like to pass a HashMap to an adapter so I can use it in a custom layout I made.

Most of the responses I have seen on the Internet involve using Parcelable, but I do not believe that JSONObject (nor HashMap for that matter) are Parcelable objects. I have tried implementing this within the CarListing class, but Android Studio does not like that I pass a JSONObject as the constructor object.

So what would be the best method of making my custom object Parcelable? Should I do the JSON parsing outside of the constructor (i.e. in my HttpGet thread), and then pass all 20-25 values as parameters? I think my biggest issue is with the constructor, but I may be incorrect. Any help is appreciated, I can provide more information if necessary.

Here is the code for my custom object, CarListing:

```
package com.example.carsearchapp;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CarListing
{
    /* vehicle parameters */
    String make, model, trim, vin, color, condition, transmission, engine, drivetype, seller_type, seller_name, website, city, state;
    int year, price, mileage, cylinders;
    double distance;
    ArrayList<String> images;

    /* carfax parameters */
    boolean one_owner, clean_title;

    /* local variables that may be important */
    int index;
    JSONObject img_json, build, dealer;
    JSONArray img_array;

    public HashMap<String, String> listview_hashmap;

    /* Most strings are default N/A. Most integers are default 1, or 1970 for the case of years. */
    public CarListing(JSONObject input, int index)
    {
        try
        {
            this.images = new ArrayList<>();
            this.index = index;
            this.listview_hashmap = new HashMap<>();

            if(input.has("vin")) this.vin = input.getString("vin");
            else this.vin = "N/A";

            if(input.has("price")) this.price = input.getInt("price");
            else this.price = 1;

            if(input.has("mileage")) this.mileage = input.getInt("mileage");
            else this.mileage = 1;

            if(input.has("vdp_url")) this.website = input.getString("vdp_url");
            else this.website = "N/A";

            if(input.has("carfax_1_owner")) this.one_owner = input.getBoolean("carfax_1_owner");
            else this.one_owner = true;

            if(input.has("carfax_clean_title")) this.clean_title = input.getBoolean("carfax_clean_title");
            else this.clean_title = true;

            if(input.has("exterior_color")) this.color = input.getString("exterior_color");
            else this.color = "N/A";

            if(input.has("seller_type")) this.seller_type = input.getString("seller_type");
            else this.seller_type = "N/A";

            if(input.has("inventory_type")) this.condition = input.getString("inventory_type");
            else this.condition = "N/A";

            if(input.has("build"))
            {
                this.build = input.getJSONObject("build");

                if(this.build.has("year")) this.year = this.build.getInt("year");
                else this.year = 1970;

                if(this.build.has("make")) this.make = this.build.getString("make");
                else this.make = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("model")) this.model = this.build.getString("model");
                else this.model = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("trim")) this.trim = this.build.getString("trim");
                else this.trim = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("transmission")) this.transmission = this.build.getString("transmission");
                else this.transmission = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("drivetrain")) this.drivetype = this.build.getString("drivetrain");
                else this.drivetype = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("cylinders")) this.cylinders = this.build.getInt("cylinders");
                else this.cylinders = 4;

                if(this.build.has("engine")) this.engine = this.build.getString("engine");
                else this.engine = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("dist")) this.distance = this.build.getDouble("dist");
                else this.distance = 0;
            }

            if(input.has("dealer"))
            {
                this.dealer = input.getJSONObject("dealer");
                if(this.dealer.has("name")) this.seller_name = capitalizeLetters(this.dealer.getString("name"));
                else this.seller_name = "N/A";

                if(this.dealer.has("city")) this.city = this.dealer.getString("city");
                else this.city = "N/A";

                if(this.dealer.has("state")) this.state = this.dealer.getString("state");
                else this.state = "N/A";
            }

            if(input.has("media"))
            {
                this.img_json = input.getJSONObject("media");
                if(this.img_json.has("photo_links")) this.img_array = this.img_json.getJSONArray("photo_links");
                else this.img_json = null;

                int n = this.img_array.length();
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                    if(i >= 50) break;
                    else
                    {
                        this.images.add(img_array.getString(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("JSON Exception thrown");
        }
    }

    public String capitalizeLetters(String input)
    {
        String[] array = input.split(" ");
        String output = "";
        int n = array.length;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            String cap = array[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + array[i].substring(1);
            output += cap;
        }
        return output;
    }

    public void makeHashMap()
    {
        String vehicle_title = Integer.toString(this.year) + this.make + this.model + this.trim;
        String vehicle_information = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(this.mileage) + " miles | " + this.color + " | " + this.condition + " | $" + NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(this.price);
        String dealer_name = this.seller_name;
        String location = Double.toString(this.distance) + " mi. | " + this.city + ", " + this.state;
        String first_img = this.images.get(0);

        this.listview_hashmap.put("title", vehicle_title);
        this.listview_hashmap.put("information", vehicle_information);
        this.listview_hashmap.put("dealer", dealer_name);
        this.listview_hashmap.put("distance", location);
        this.listview_hashmap.put("first_image", first_img);
    }
}
```

Comment: The parcelable implementation is independent from the constructor that you have, you should keep your class as is, with the JSON constructor and then have the parcelable implementation with your static CREATOR and your parcel constructor together with your writeToParcel method which are the required implementation. You should leave your JSONObject and JSONArray outside of the parcelable implementation... If you need to keep them, just save them as a String instead which is supported by the parcel.

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the explanation, I was able to solve the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! There are four main parameters I had to add to this class to get it to be Parcelable.

The first was a protected constructor that took in a Parcel object.

The second was a new static CREATOR object, with internal methods createFromParcel and newArray.

The third was the describeContents function.

Lastly was the writeToParcel function.

Hopefully others are able to learn from this, and sorry if this could be considered a repost!

The modified code can be seen below:

```
package com.example.marketcheckcarsearchapp;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CarListing implements Parcelable
{
    /* vehicle parameters */
    String make, model, trim, vin, color, condition, transmission, engine, drivetype, seller_type, seller_name, website, city, state;
    int year, price, mileage, cylinders;
    double distance;
    ArrayList<String> images;

    /* carfax parameters */
    boolean one_owner, clean_title;

    /* local variables that may be important */
    int index;
    JSONObject img_json, build, dealer;
    JSONArray img_array;

    public HashMap<String, String> listview_hashmap;

    /* Most strings are default N/A. Most integers are default 1, or 1970 for the case of years. */
    public CarListing(JSONObject input, int index)
    {
        try
        {
            this.images = new ArrayList<>();
            this.index = index;
            this.listview_hashmap = new HashMap<>();

            if(input.has("vin")) this.vin = input.getString("vin");
            else this.vin = "N/A";

            if(input.has("price")) this.price = input.getInt("price");
            else this.price = 1;

            if(input.has("mileage")) this.mileage = input.getInt("mileage");
            else this.mileage = 1;

            if(input.has("vdp_url")) this.website = input.getString("vdp_url");
            else this.website = "N/A";

            if(input.has("carfax_1_owner")) this.one_owner = input.getBoolean("carfax_1_owner");
            else this.one_owner = true;

            if(input.has("carfax_clean_title")) this.clean_title = input.getBoolean("carfax_clean_title");
            else this.clean_title = true;

            if(input.has("exterior_color")) this.color = input.getString("exterior_color");
            else this.color = "N/A";

            if(input.has("seller_type")) this.seller_type = input.getString("seller_type");
            else this.seller_type = "N/A";

            if(input.has("inventory_type")) this.condition = input.getString("inventory_type");
            else this.condition = "N/A";

            if(input.has("build"))
            {
                this.build = input.getJSONObject("build");

                if(this.build.has("year")) this.year = this.build.getInt("year");
                else this.year = 1970;

                if(this.build.has("make")) this.make = this.build.getString("make");
                else this.make = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("model")) this.model = this.build.getString("model");
                else this.model = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("trim")) this.trim = this.build.getString("trim");
                else this.trim = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("transmission")) this.transmission = this.build.getString("transmission");
                else this.transmission = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("drivetrain")) this.drivetype = this.build.getString("drivetrain");
                else this.drivetype = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("cylinders")) this.cylinders = this.build.getInt("cylinders");
                else this.cylinders = 4;

                if(this.build.has("engine")) this.engine = this.build.getString("engine");
                else this.engine = "N/A";

                if(this.build.has("dist")) this.distance = this.build.getDouble("dist");
                else this.distance = 0;
            }

            if(input.has("dealer"))
            {
                this.dealer = input.getJSONObject("dealer");
                if(this.dealer.has("name")) this.seller_name = capitalizeLetters(this.dealer.getString("name"));
                else this.seller_name = "N/A";

                if(this.dealer.has("city")) this.city = this.dealer.getString("city");
                else this.city = "N/A";

                if(this.dealer.has("state")) this.state = this.dealer.getString("state");
                else this.state = "N/A";
            }

            if(input.has("media"))
            {
                this.img_json = input.getJSONObject("media");
                if(this.img_json.has("photo_links")) this.img_array = this.img_json.getJSONArray("photo_links");
                else this.img_json = null;

                int n = this.img_array.length();
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                    if(i >= 50) break;
                    else
                    {
                        this.images.add(img_array.getString(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("JSON Exception thrown");
        }
    }

    protected CarListing(Parcel in) {
        make = in.readString();
        model = in.readString();
        trim = in.readString();
        vin = in.readString();
        color = in.readString();
        condition = in.readString();
        transmission = in.readString();
        engine = in.readString();
        drivetype = in.readString();
        seller_type = in.readString();
        seller_name = in.readString();
        website = in.readString();
        city = in.readString();
        state = in.readString();
        year = in.readInt();
        price = in.readInt();
        mileage = in.readInt();
        cylinders = in.readInt();
        distance = in.readDouble();
        images = in.createStringArrayList();
        one_owner = in.readByte() != 0;
        clean_title = in.readByte() != 0;
        index = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<CarListing> CREATOR = new Creator<CarListing>() {
        @Override
        public CarListing createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CarListing(in);
        }

        @Override
        public CarListing[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CarListing[size];
        }
    };

    public String capitalizeLetters(String input)
    {
        String[] array = input.split(" ");
        String output = "";
        int n = array.length;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            String cap = array[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + array[i].substring(1);
            output += cap;
        }
        return output;
    }

    public void makeHashMap()
    {
        String vehicle_title = Integer.toString(this.year) + this.make + this.model + this.trim;
        String vehicle_information = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(this.mileage) + " miles | " + this.color + " | " + this.condition + " | $" + NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(this.price);
        String dealer_name = this.seller_name;
        String location = Double.toString(this.distance) + " mi. | " + this.city + ", " + this.state;
        String first_img = this.images.get(0);

        this.listview_hashmap.put("title", vehicle_title);
        this.listview_hashmap.put("information", vehicle_information);
        this.listview_hashmap.put("dealer", dealer_name);
        this.listview_hashmap.put("distance", location);
        this.listview_hashmap.put("first_image", first_img);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(make);
        dest.writeString(model);
        dest.writeString(trim);
        dest.writeString(vin);
        dest.writeString(color);
        dest.writeString(condition);
        dest.writeString(transmission);
        dest.writeString(engine);
        dest.writeString(drivetype);
        dest.writeString(seller_type);
        dest.writeString(seller_name);
        dest.writeString(website);
        dest.writeString(city);
        dest.writeString(state);
        dest.writeInt(year);
        dest.writeInt(price);
        dest.writeInt(mileage);
        dest.writeInt(cylinders);
        dest.writeDouble(distance);
        dest.writeStringList(images);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (one_owner ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeByte((byte) (clean_title ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeInt(index);
    }
}
```